# How can I output the contents of a scripted array in a google sheets?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a totally new to coding and Google App script, so I humbly ask my question.

I have look all over the place for an answer to this problem and can't seem to find a way to solve it.

Below is my code that gets data from Google Sheets based on their IDs. I can bring the data in and add for 4 sheets and from a particular range.

The script successfully stores the data in an array(arr).

The script sends the data the size of the original import range to the active sheet.

But, how can I output all of the data I can see logged in the array (arr)?
I've tried changing the range size of the output, but to no avail, it just causes and error.

```
   function GetData() {
        var classes = ["1XN9NPs_irdpVBEuy0saY-m_PjMW8BxIOgvLkaekdMXo",     
        "1XN9NPs_irdpVBEuy0saY-m_PjMW8BxIOgvLkaekdMXo", 
        "11Pdsixi17YjtePg4L780mtGkElWU7TUmshYtJnzxbMU", 
        "11y8ILVN3lTCWaQYr0nhLdDdLsDDoRqcR2BHz42leUbI"];
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
        var exSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById(classes[j]);        
        var exSheet = exSs.getSheetByName("tastodolist");
        var range = "A4:F10"
        var exRange = exSheet.getRange(range);
        var values = exRange.getValues();
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(values);

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

         //The log contains all the data that is needed. 
            Logger.log(arr[i]);

        }
        //I'm struggling to get all of the logged data into the active            
        sheet - my code can only output 7 rows of data. 

       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,7,6).setValues(arr[i]);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting 7 rows and 6 columns of the sheet, get all the array's size to output it entirely:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr[i]);
```

Also, this is primarily a [google-apps-script] question.